# Does xgb.train handle grid parameter search

Tags: r, xgboost

I'm trying to determine what xgb.train is doing in the below case.

Will it actually iterate through the various parameters in my grid, or is it just training the model on the first set of parameters in the grid?

Most examples I'm finding are based on the train function not on xgb.train.

```
require(xgboost)

data(agaricus.train, package='xgboost')
data(agaricus.test, package='xgboost')

dtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(agaricus.train$data, label = agaricus.train$label)
dtest <- xgb.DMatrix(agaricus.test$data, label = agaricus.test$label)

watchlist <- list(train = dtrain, eval = dtest)

xgb_grid_1 <- expand.grid(booster = "gbtree" 
, objective = "binary:logistic"
, scale_neg_weight = 1
, eta=c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6)
, gamma=0
, max_depth=c(1,5,10,15,20)
, min_child_weight=1
, subsample=1
, colsample_bytree=1)

mod_obj <- xgb.train (params = xgb_grid
, data = dtrain
, nrounds = 250
, watchlist = list(val=dtest,train=dtrain)
, print_every_n = 10
, early_stop_round = 10
, maximize = F
, eval_metric = "logloss")
```

Comment: Hi Pine, welcome to SO, I reccomend that you post a reprex when asking questions, as it stands we can't replicate your data and as such you reduce the number of people capable of answering your question to those that already know what xgb.train does or those that will have to actually search a new dataset to test

Comment: Updated with reprex.